# subscript in legend items without using scale_color_manual in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I use subscript (A_0) in the legend items of this example without using scale_color_manual(label = ...)?

I appreciate your help.

```
a = data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10), z = rep(c(1:5),2))
a$label = paste0('z', a$z, ':','A[0]')
a %>%
ggplot2::ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, color = label, group = label)) + 
  geom_point(size = 7, stroke = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: From the dup, try `scale_color_discrete(labels = setNames(lapply(unique(a$label), str2expression), unique(a$label)))`

Comment: There's no way not to use `scale_color_manual` (or related functions), why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Actually you could just do `scale_color_discrete(labels = str2expression)` if you don't need more fine grained control.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the duplicate link ?